# 2 dummy variables in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dummy-variable

I have a dataframe x_0 of 5 numeric variables and 2 categorical variables:
['v1',
'v2',
'v3',
'v4',
'v5',
'v6',
'v7']

I want to convert v6 and v7 to dummy variables. I have tried with the following code but I receive a traceback:

```
x = pd.concat([x_0['v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4', 'v5'], pd.get_dummies(x_0['v6', 'v7'])], axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double `[]` for selecting by multiple columns names:

```
x = pd.concat([x_0[['v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4', 'v5']], 
               pd.get_dummies(x_0[['v6', 'v7']])], axis = 1)
```

Comment: it does not give an error, however it does not convert it to dummies..

Comment: @codeforfun - It is weird, how working add `.astype(str)` like `pd.get_dummies(x_0[['v6', 'v7']].astype(str)` ?